# Multiple necessary conditions in grepl

Tags: r

I need to create a cathegorical variable (**new_var**) based on some conditions. The variable containing those conditions (var) is in text format such as:

| var | new_var |
| --- | --- |
| L: 06:00-22:00 (A) | A |
| L: 00:00-07:59 (D), 07:59-23:59 (A) | MIXED |
| L-V: 08:00-21:00 (A), 07:59-23:59 (A) | A |
| S: 08:00-19:00 (D) | D |

So, the conditions for creating the new variable are between brakets. Can be A, D, or MIXED (A & D).

I tried the following code:

```
var = as.character(c('L: 06:00-22:00 (A)', 'L: 00:00-07:59 (D), 07:59-23:59 (A)', 'L-V: 08:00-21:00 (A), 07:59-23:59 (A)', 'S: 08:00-19:00 (D)'))
df<- as.data.frame(var)


   df<- df%>% 
 mutate(new_var = case_when(
   grepl("(D).*(A)", df$var) ~ "MIXED", 
   grepl("(A)", df$var) ~ "A", 
   grepl("(D)", df$var) ~ "D",
   T ~ "N/A"))
```

But creates the **newvar** imprecisely, with errors.

Comment: Provide `dput(df)` data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it have to be using tidyverse piping?

If not, here are some steps you could try:

```
x <- c('L: 06:00-22:00 (A)', 'L: 00:00-07:59 (D), 07:59-23:59 (A)', 'L-V: 08:00-21:00 (A), 07:59-23:59 (A)', 'S: 08:00-19:00 (D)')

m <- gregexpr('(?<=\\()[AD](?=\\))', x, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "D" "A"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "A"

[[4]]
[1] "D"

new_var <- lapply(regmatches(x, m), unique)

new_var[sapply(new_var, length) > 1] <- 'MIXED'
unlist(new_var)
```